# Fabric - unable to add iPhone Xs Max, iPhone Xs device for beta testing

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile, google-fabric, ios12

In the Fabric app, after adding iPhone Xs Max or iPhone Xs device in the provisioning profile, devices are not detecting inside the application.
It is showing the error message "We couldn't locate the following devices in your profile:"

Comment: Im having a similar problem.  With no solution.

Comment: @theprojectabot hi just update to the latest fabric app and crashlytics solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Mike from Fabric here. We had a bug that prevented the installs from going through on the new iPhones. We've now fixed the bug, so re-installing the app should go fine now.

Comment: I just installed the Fabric app from https://fabric.io/download , after deleting the old one, and this issue still happens. I can see the iPhone Max's ID in the *.mobileprovision file (under ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/) yet the Fabric App states "We couldn't locate the following devices in your profile". What else could I try?

Comment: That warning will remain present while we do other work, but the install should happen.

Comment: Hi, @MikeBonnell, Do i need to re-install the macOS app for distribution?, or re-install the testing app?

Comment: @MikeBonnell same issue

Comment: Again, the warning will be present, but the installation should not be prevented. If you're seeing that, raise a new question with more details.

Comment: @NobinThomas re-install the testing app or re-click the link to install the app.

Comment: Re-install the application works fine in iPhone Xs Max. The warning in the mac OS app still persists.

Comment: Yep, that's expected for now.

Comment: @MikeBonnell this issue is still persisting for us. Is something still preventing installs on iPhone Xs's?

Comment: None that I'm aware of and given the lack of additional comments, I'd be surprised by a wide spread issue. I'd recommend reaching out to support(at)fabric(dot)io.